# Cypress arrayBuffer viene vacio

Tags: javascript, array, testing, cypress

Estoy realizando una prueba en cypress, el objetivo de la misma es obtener un arreglo de urls que vienen desde Contentful, recorrer ese arreglo de urls y validar que ninguna de ellas venga con status code 500 y que no contengan pantalla de error. Tuve que hacer una excepcion en el codigo para que cuando detecte status code=500 no se interrumpa la prueba, ya que la idea seria que al finalizar el recorrido del array consolee un mensaje que me diga que urls son las que vienen con error.
Mi problema esta que al realizar un console.log(response) verifico que de hecho la url y su contenido estan cargados en el arreglo, pero al consolear "data" (que convierte el arraybuffer) el mismo viene vacio y ya no puedo validar nada.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
     import { getPagesFromContentful } from '../../support/getPagesFromContentful';
import '../../support/commands';
describe('Mi prueba', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.clearLocalStorage(); // Limpiar el almacenamiento local
    cy.clearCookies();
  });

  it('prueba pagina parte 1', () => {
    getPagesFromContentful().then((response) => {
      cy.wrap(response).as('pagesUrls');
      const errores = [];

      cy.get('@pagesUrls').each((url) => {
        cy.request({
          url: url,
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          failOnStatusCode: false, // No detener la prueba en caso de error de estado
          responseType: 'arraybuffer',
        }).then((response) => {
          console.log('hola', response);
          const data = new Uint8Array(response.body); // Convertir el ArrayBuffer a un formato adecuado (por ejemplo, Uint8Array)
          console.log('hi', data);

          const content = new TextDecoder().decode(data); // Decodificar el contenido a texto
          console.log('hallo', content);

          // Realizar las comprobaciones en el contenido
          try {
            cy.wrap(content).should('not.contain', 'error-page');
          } catch (error) {
            const errorMensaje = `Error en la posición ${url}: ${
              error.message
            }\n\nContenido del arreglo: ${JSON.stringify(content)}`;
            //debugger;
            errores.push(errorMensaje);
            cy.log(errorMensaje);
            //debugger;
          }
        });
      });
      if (errores.length > 0) {
        // Si hay errores, mostrarlos y fallar el test
        const errorMessage = `Se encontraron ${errores.length} errores:\n\n${errores.join('\n\n')}`;
        cy.log(errorMessage);
        throw new Error(errorMessage);
      }
    });
  });
});
```